# Compare two arrays and push same element in one array and rest in other array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, lodash

Compare two arrays and push same element in one array and rest in other array in javascript

```
const arr1 = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'p', 'r', 'l'];

const arr2 = ['e', 'r'];

**Expected response :**

Same elements ['e', 'r']
different elements ['a', 'c', 'j', 'l']

expected array : ['ac', 'e', 'jp', 'r', 'l']
```

I have tried this is it correct way ?

```
const res = [];
  let txt = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
        res.push(txt);
        res.push(arr2[j]);
        j += 1;
        txt = '';
      } else if (j === arr2.length - 1) {
        txt += `${arr1[i]} `;
        if (i === arr1.length - 1) {
          res.push(txt);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: _.difference if lodash?

Comment: @Andy updated can you please suggest if you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Does your code work? If it does it's the correct way. There maybe other ways of achieving the same result but that would be outside the scope of your question.

Comment: @Andy If you have any suggestion please let me know  any other way to achieve this like from lodash function ?

Comment: What do you do in the case of duplicates?

Comment: In my this case there will be no chance of duplicates but only two array have same element will be possible

Comment: How is this `expected array : ['ac', 'e', 'jp', 'r', 'l']` generated?

Comment: Yeah, above code i have tried and its working fine. So, i have just questions is it correct or not? If not or any other way to simplify the code then please let me know 

Comment: *"its working fine [...] is it correct or not?"*: if it would not be correct it would not be working fine? In my book "working fine" is synonymous to "is correct".

Answer (score 0):

By observing your expected array and your own code segment I could guess what you are trying to achieve (It's not full clear from your problem statement). If my understanding is correct then your code might not result in expected answer in all cases if the input array is not fixed. I have modified your code as below. Have a check. set arr2 input as ['e', 'r', 't'] , or ['a', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'p', 'r', 'l'] and check the output. Let me know if it's helpful.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
        if(txt!=='') res.push(txt)
        res.push(arr2[j]);
        txt = '';
        break;
      } 
      else if (j === arr2.length - 1) {
        txt+= txt===''?`${arr1[i]}` : ` ${arr1[i]}`
        if (i === arr1.length - 1) {
          res.push(txt);
        }
      }
    }
 }
```